# Inline view limitations

Tags: sql, oracle, inline-view

```
SELECT in_ev.type, pl.name, in_ev.year
FROM places pl INNER JOIN (SELECT e.type, e.place_id, e.year 
                           FROM events e)in_ev ON in_ev.place_id=pl.place_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM in_ev sub_ev WHERE sub_ev.year=1994)
```

I'm trying to understand how inline views are processed and why we cannot use them as a "source table" in where clause subqueries. When I try to run this query I get *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*

Above snippet is only for illustration reasons.

What is the exact difference in storage and processing between ordinary tables and inline views?

Answer (score 1):

The subquery in the `where` clause just can't see the inline view, which I guess you've figured out; it's a scope issue, really. There is no storage, and how it's managed in memory and processed is somewhat down to the optimiser - it may substantially rewrite things, for instance. The subquery might logically be evaluated before the inline view is evaluated, I suppose.

As the parser is throwing the ORA-00942 before the query is actually executed, how the inline view is handled is a bit of a moot point.

You can use subquery factoring instead:

```
WITH in_ev AS (
  SELECT e.type, e.place_id, e.year 
  FROM events e
)
SELECT in_ev.type, pl.name, in_ev.year
FROM places pl INNER JOIN in_ev ON in_ev.place_id=pl.place_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM in_ev sub_ev WHERE sub_ev.year=1994)
```

Which looks odd with such a contrived example, but you acknowleged that it's illustrative in the question. The subquery in the `where` clause *can* see the CTE - it is in scope to the parser.

As @mathguy noted in a comment, the optimiser may still treat the CTE as a subquery, but that's not normally something you need to worry about - particularly if you're just trying to avoid the error you were getting.

Comment: To add to Alex's explanation, and further answer the question about evaluation and storage: When the Optimizer sees a factored subquery (the "view" in the WITH clause), it is free to consider two options and choose the one it thinks is more efficient. One is to treat it as an inline view (evaluating it in-place both in the FROM and in the WHERE clauses); OR, it can treat it as a temporary global table, computing it only once, saving it and using it just as it might use a stored table where it is used in the rest of the query. Which option the CBO will choose depends on several things.